# What Prettier rule is adding {' '} between tags?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, prettier, tsx

With a block of TSX markup like so:

```jsx
<div className='mb-2'>
  Start an <strong className='text-textblack'>Open Session</strong> by tapping "Begin Session", or choose a specific <strong className='text-textblack'>Session Topic</strong> below.
</div>
```

My formatting will insert `{' '}` like so:

```typescript
<div className="mb-2">
  Start an <strong className="text-textblack">Open Session</strong>{' '}
  by tapping "Begin Session", or choose a specific{' '}
  <strong className="text-textblack">Session Topic</strong> below.
</div>

I cannot locate what rule is making this happen, but it's driving me nuts.
```

Comment: If it wouldn't insert that, the whitespace would get stripped away by React (rendering "Sessionby" and "specificSession"). I doubt it's a specific rule, it's just the necessary refactoring when a rule needs to break lines in JSX (e.g. because prettier considers them too long)

Comment: What does your configuration for prettier look like?